# MapHubs not needed in SignalR 1.01?

Tags: signalr

I am following the Hubs Quick Start Guide in the Signalr Wiki.   I get an error in Global.asax, Application_Start on the line RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs().

A route named 'signalr.hubs' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique.
Parameter name: name

Maybe this is not needed anymore in 1.0.1?  It worked fine in 1.0.  It is also mentioned in the readme.txt from NuGet that we need the MapHubs command.

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code   Message=A route
>   named 'signalr.hubs' is already in the route collection. Route names
>   must be unique. Parameter name: name   Source=System.Web
>   ParamName=name   StackTrace:
>          at System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.Add(String name, RouteBase item)
>          at System.Web.Routing.RouteCollectionExtensions.Add[T](RouteCollection
>   routes, String name, T item)
>          at System.Web.Routing.RouteCollectionExtensions.MapOwinPath(RouteCollection
>   routes, String name, String pathBase, Action`1 startup)
>          at System.Web.Routing.SignalRRouteExtensions.MapHubs(RouteCollection
>   routes, String name, String path, HubConfiguration configuration)
>          at System.Web.Routing.SignalRRouteExtensions.MapHubs(RouteCollection
>   routes, String path, HubConfiguration configuration)
>          at System.Web.Routing.SignalRRouteExtensions.MapHubs(RouteCollection
>   routes, HubConfiguration configuration)
>          at System.Web.Routing.SignalRRouteExtensions.MapHubs(RouteCollection
>   routes)
>          at SignalrServer.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\RC\Code\Signalr\SignalrServer\SignalrServer\Global.asax.cs:line 18 
>   InnerException:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need it. Looks like you're calling it twice in your app, don't do that. If you're not explicitly calling it twice then you have and older version of signalr that used to call it for you lying around somewhere in your bin folder. Delete it all and it should work.

Comment: Correct.  In my 1.1 upgraded solution, App_Start folder I have a RegisterHubs.cs file that uses RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs().  Removed this and everything works great!  Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes it is in the `Global.asax`