# SignalR map hubs

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, signalr

I am using SignalR to build Real time application
I have added the following code to application start in the global.asax file

```
'Register the default hubs route: ~/signalr
 RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs()
```

and I got the following error:

A route named 'signalr.hubs' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique.
Parameter name: name

Comment: Have you looked at the troubleshooting section of the SignalR documentation? This issue is addressed there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MapHubs not needed in SignalR 1.01?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166040/maphubs-not-needed-in-signalr-1-01)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely you are calling this twice.  Check all your code that this is not the case, including any App_Start code.  Do a global search within your app for "MapHubs".

Also check you have only one version of Signal installed (older versions had a different namespace).