# SignalR multiple hubs on different paths in same application?

Tags: c#, signalr

I have an application which contains multiple hubs all on unique paths, so when calling the default :

`routes.MapHubs("path", new HubConfiguration(...));`

It blows up saying that the signalr.hubs is already defined (as mentioned here [MapHubs not needed in SignalR 1.01?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166040/maphubs-not-needed-in-signalr-1-01)).

Now I can understand that it should only be called once, but then you will only get 1 path, so is there any way to handle a path per hub scenario? like how with MVC you specify the controller and action? so something like:

`routes.MapHub<SomeHub>("path", new HubConfiguration(...));`

== Edit for more info ==

It is mentioned often that you should never need to call this map hubs more than once, and in *most* scenarios I can agree, however I would not say that this is going to be the case for all applications.

In this scenario it is a website which at runtime loads any plugins which are available, each plugin is exposed the dependency injection framework to include its dependencies and the route table to include its routes. The hubs may have nothing to do with each other (other than the fact that they are both hub objects). So the hubs are not all known up front and are only known after the plugins are loaded, and yes I could wait until after this and try binding the hubs there, however then how do I have custom routes for each one then?

This seems to be a case of SignalR trying to abstract a little too much, as I dont see it being a bad idea to have custom routes rather than the default "/signalr", and as the routes all have different responsibilities it seems bad to have one entry route for them all.

So anyway I think the question still stands, as I dont see this as being a bad use case or bad design it just seems to be that I want to be able to have a route with a hub applied to it, much like in mvc you apply a controller and action to a route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need more than the `signalr.hubs` route. If you point your browser to that route, you will see it automatically finds all public types assignable to `IHub` and creates a JavaScript proxy for them. You can interact with different hubs by name from JavaScript, i.e. if you have the following Hub:

```
public class GameHub : Hub
```

You can connect to that specific hub by doing:

```
var gameHubProxy = $.connection.gameHub;
```

You can also explicitly specify a name for your hub by adding the `HubNameAttribute` to the class:

```
[HubName("AwesomeHub")]
public class GameHub : Hub
```

You can then retrieve the specific proxy by doing

```
var awesomeHubProxy = $.connection.awesomeHub;
```

**UPDATE:**

I'm not sure whether SignalR will be able to run on multiple paths in the same application. It could potentially mess things up and the default assembly locator won't be able to pick up hubs loaded at runtime anyway.

However, there is a solution where you can implement your own `IAssemblyLocator` that will pick up hubs from your plugin assemblies:

```
public class PluginAssemblyLocator : DefaultAssemblyLocator
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Assembly> _pluginAssemblies;

    public PluginAssemblyLocator(IEnumerable<Assembly> pluginAssemblies)
    {
        _pluginAssemblies = pluginAssemblies;
    }

    public override IList<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        return base.GetAssemblies().Union(_pluginAssemblies).ToList();
    }
}
```

After you've loaded your plugins, you should call `MapHubs` and register an override of SignalRs `IAssemblyLocator` service:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Load plugins and let them specify their own routes (but not for hubs).
    var pluginAssemblies = LoadPlugins(RouteTable.Routes);

    RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();

    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IAssemblyLocator), () => new PluginAssemblyLocator(pluginAssemblies));
}
```

**NOTE:** Register the `IAssemblyLocator` *AFTER* you've called `MapHubs` because it will also override it.

Now, there *are* issues with this approach. If you're using the static JavaScript proxy, it won't be re-generated every time it's accessed. This means that if your `/signalr/hubs` proxy is accessed before all plugins/hubs has been loaded, they won't be picked up. You can get around this by either making sure that all hubs are loaded by the time you map the route or by not using the static proxy at all.

This solution still requires you to get a reference to your plugin assemblies, I hope that's feasible...

Comment: Problem is these hubs have nothing to do with each other and are hosted within runtime loaded plugins for the website, so when the app starts it looks for all injectable plugins and loads them in, letting them load their dependencies and routes. So it is not possible for me to split them out. Will add an edit to the question showing this.

Comment: So the plugins _need_ their own routes (for hubs)? Can't you resolve the hubs from the loaded assemblies/plugins instead? Even though the `signalr.hubs` route is registered in `Application_Start`, the hubs won't be resolved until later...

Comment: They dont *NEED* their own routes, it just makes sense to give them their own routes as they are all segregated blocks of logic. The plugins are resolved via MEF at application launch, so it will do the application DI config and routing, then it delegates to each plugin, and currently I have about 6 plugins, 2 of which register hubs, and both call the `route.MapHubs` which is the problem. As you may have 1 of those plugins, or all 6 of those plugins so getting the last loaded plugin to do the registering or move the at logic to the root application host seems only option. Neither seem good.

Comment: Can you call `MapHubs` after the plugins has been loaded? In that case, I may have a solution for you...

Comment: I should be able to, just worries me that the plugins are not entirely self contained now as they would require the root to do some *magic* for them to be run.

Comment: Plugins will always depend on the root to do some magic for them ;) I'll update my answer to include a potential solution...

Comment: have given you +1, I still am not too happy with this approach, as although I can do it and it works I am would have to not only have 1 url for all hubs to live within, which isnt very url descriptive (as the rest of my app is restful) and the plugins are not self registering for hubs. I will keep the question open though incase anyone has any way for me to have my cake and eat it here. I dont use the proxy generated JS clients I invoke the urls directly, so it can be mocked easier for testing.

Comment: One of the major reasons we chose to make hubs use the same connection was because of browsers resources. You only have ~6 concurrent connections to the same domain, so the idea that random plugins get to use up a whole connections might sound great but is just impractical. That said, today you can certainly map persistent connections to individual paths and you can also do the same for hubs but it's painful as you have to use a different hub discovery mechanism per route.

Comment: @dfowler any chance you could link to an example of the above as an answer and I will give you the tick? Given you a +1 as at least there is a technical reason as to why it is preferred to have 1 global url for all hubs/connections to run off. I still think that it is up to the developer to make these sort of decisions, but in 99% of cases im sure it is not an issue.

Comment: I disagree, if we made it so you had to map individual hubs people would complain when using 2 hubs uses up all of their available browser connections and now they can't even make ajax requests. That said, if you did want to shoot yourself in the foot we could make that easier by allowing you to say which hubs would be mapped to which url. What @KristianHellang describes is how you would do it. Use a custom assembly resolver per Route. You don't have to use GlobalHost.xxx you can pass in an instance of a dependency resolver to MapHubs.

Comment: I am not saying force the developer to do one or the other, im saying let them choose either solution, and you are assuming that I would be wanting to run both hubs at the same time. This is incorrect they are used in 2 completely different pages (which again come from their relative plugins), so the point about wasting resources is moot in this instance as you are still only connecting to one hub. If I can achieve the url per hub via custom dependency resolvers then at least I can keep everything self contained and urls descriptive, rather than a global "signalr/" route.

Comment: @davidfowl One might also want different concepts of authentication or identity for the connection to a specific hub, and also not everybody is using a browser on the client side. There's plenty of reasons, and signalr forces a bit much onto the user in my opinion.